# Plot with a grid

Tags: r, graph, plot, data.table

I am looking for a type of plot that is essentially a grid. For example, there will be 10 columns and 50 rows. For example, something like this:

[image]

Each of the boxes (in this case, 10*50 = 500) will have a unique value that I will be providing via a data frame. Based on the unique values, I'll have a function that will assign a colour to each box. So then it becomes a grid to visualize "the range" of each box. I'd also need to label each of the columns (probably vertically so all labels fit) and rows (horizontally).

I just don't know what kind of plot that will be and I don't know if any libraries do this. I'm just looking for some help in finding something that does this. I'd appreciate some help if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `heatmap`?

```
m=matrix(runif(12),3,4)
rownames(m)=c("Me","You","Him")
colnames(m)=c("We","Us","Them","I")
heatmap(m,NA,NA)
```

[image]

Note that it works on a `matrix` and not a `data frame` because all the values have to be numbers, and `data frames` are row-oriented records.

See the help for other options.

Comment: This is great. Is it possible to return a data frame or matrix of all the colours in the heatmap? I have to correlate colours from some of the grids with another scatterplot.

Comment: Rather, is there a way of input my own colours for the heatmap? All the numbers will be from 0 to 100 and I can have a window of 10 each. So, 0 to 10 would be one colour, 10+ to 20 another, and so on until 100.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the help for heatmap describes how to control the palette. Have you tried?

Comment: I'm using heatmap.2, which is similar to heatmap. heatmap.2 has colours and breaks that I'm using for the ranges. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the `image` function in the graphics package, or the `rasterImage` function if you want more control.

You could also build the plot up from scratch using the `rect` function.

Answer (score 4):

I would go to `ggplot2` for this as it allows a high degree of flexibility. In particular `geom_tile` is useful. If you actually want the panel lines you can comment out the `theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +` and  `theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +` lines and of course you can specify the colours as well. The text in each cell is optional; comment out the `geom_text` call if you don't need that. Note that you can control the size of the plot (rows and columns) simply by resizing the plot window or - if you want to output to a file using `png()` - by specifying the `width` and `height` arguments.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(scales)

set.seed(1234)
num.els <- 5
mydf <- data.frame(category1 = rep(LETTERS[1:num.els], 1, each = num.els),
                   category2 = rep(1:num.els, num.els),
                   value = runif(num.els^2, 0, 100))

p <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = category1,
                      y = category2,
                      fill = value)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(label = round(mydf$value, 2), size = 4, colour = "black") +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red",
                         limits = c(min(mydf$value), max(mydf$value)),
                         midpoint = median(mydf$value)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_reverse() +
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    theme()

print(p)
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

And resized:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a dataframe with "**x**" and "**y**" coordinates per each cell of the grid, and a variable "**z**" for each cell, and you loaded this dataframe in R called "**intlgrid**":

`head(intlgrid)`

```
      x       y        z 

243.742 6783.367 0.0035285

244.242 6783.367 0.0037111

244.742 6783.367 0.0039073

"..."
"so on..."
```

With ggplot2 package you can easily plot your raster. So:

`install.packages("ggplot2")`

once installed ggplot2, you just call it

`library(ggplot2)`

Now the code:

`ggplot(intlgrid, aes(x,y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() + coord_equal()`

And then you get your grid plotted.

Comment: `ggplot2` also has `geom_tile` which is meant for this sort of thing.